# .htaccess URL rewrite to upper-case characters in domain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, url

For example, I'd like to have **foobar.com** show **FooBar.com**

This *almost* works, but ends up forcing a redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foobar.com\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://FooBar.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there any way to do this? I know it's weird, but I'm just curious if it's possible to do without ending up in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - a client browser will always lowercase it before sending the `Host` HTTP header, so it'll always redirect loop.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the answer I was looking for. I noticed my browser wouldn't keep an upper-case domain name, but I didn't know why.